# Inequality of complex numbers modulus

Tags: complex-numbers

Someone could help to prove the following inequality of modulus of complex numbers:

If $a\in\mathbb{C}$ then $$|a|\leq|a+z| \qquad \forall z\in\mathbb{C}$$

Answer (score 3):

It will be hard to prove.  Try $a=1, z=-1$ where it is false.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't true.

$$a=1+i,\;z=-1-i$$

Comment: and if $z\neq -a$?

Comment: @Andres Still not I'm afraid - example: $a=i,\;z=-i/2$

Comment: Julien and this inequality is true?

Comment: Julien and this inequality is true?\\\\ $$|a_n|\leq\left|a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{z}+\frac{a_{n-2}}{z^2}+...+\frac{a_{1}}{z^{n-1}}+\frac{a_{0}}{z^{n}}\right|$$ with $z\neq 0$, $a_n\neq 0$ and  $a_k\in \mathbb{C}$ for $k=0, 1,...,n$

Comment: Now if Julien!!  I'm trying to make a proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra using the polynomial $ P (z) = a_ {0} + a_ {1} z + ... + a_ {n} z ^ {n} $ with $ a_ {n } \neq 0 $. and let me know if the above inequality is true

Comment: @Andres Still false. Let $a_n=1,\; a_{n-1}=-1,\;a_{n-2},\;a_{n-3}\cdots\; a_0=0,$ and $z=1$

Comment: and if $|z|\rightarrow\infty$ the inequality is true?

Comment: @Andres Well then you would be left with $|a_n|=|a_n|$ - so yes it would be true. I don't see how that limit relates to the fundamental theorem of algebra though.

Comment: Or did you mean for large $|z|$? (in which case it is still false)

Comment: Julien you know under what conditions the inequality $$|a_n|\leq\left|a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{z}+\frac{a_{n-2}}{z^2}+...+\frac{a_{1}}{z^{n‌​-1}}+\frac{a_{0}}{z^{n}}\right|$$ is true?

Answer (score 0):

This is false(!) Try $a = 1$, $z$ any negative number in $[-2, 0]$.

Comment: and if $|z|\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: For larger $z$, then your inequality can hold. But not for *all* $z$. But you said "$\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$".